# Attribute translations for multiple Active Record models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, yaml, rails-i18n

I have several related-yet-distinct AR models that contain attributes representing the same piece of data. When I set up translations for these attributes, I'm currently setting them up as...

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      model_a:
        assigned_date: "Assigned to worker"
      model_b:
        assigned_date: "Assigned to worker"
      [ ... ]
```

Is there any way to define this translation **once**, in some kind of wildcard fashion?

The approach I thought made the most sense...

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      assigned_date: "Assigned to worker"
      model_a:
        [ model-specific translations here ]
```

Doesn't work because AR is obviously looking for a model name at the tier beneath `attributes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common attributes can go one level up and been overwritten when need it

```
en:
    attributes:
        first_name: Name
    activerecord:
        attributes:
            user:
                email: Email
            admin:
                first_name: First Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could define "node anchors" and reference them later. Additionally you could redefine attributes that are defined in "node anchors" section with different value which is your requirement.

Use as follows:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    defaults: &defaults
      assigned_date: "Assigned to worker"
    attributes:
      model_a:
        <<: *defaults
        assigned_date: Model specific translation
```

In this case you define node anchor `&defaults` and reference them within `model_a`. Then you overwrite the value for `assigned_date` under `model_a`. So, `model_a.assigned_date` gives you "Model specific translation". Without the redefinition of `assigned_date` under `model_a`, `model_a.assigned_date` will give you "Assigned to worker".